# What is the USB Barcode Data Structure?

Tags: usb, barcode, hid

USB barcodes have a specific data format???

Example Keybord data format (data which coming from keyboard) is 8 bytes ( modifiers,reserved,keycode1..keycode6).

Comment: Can you clarify or provide a link to what "USB barcodes" are?

Comment: I think he means data returned from a USB barcode scanner. In my limited experience don't they pretend to be keyboards - don't they just type the data as a standard USB HID? Which scanner?

Answer (score 0):

I've had experience with a number of laser and optical barcode readers, and all of the USB-attached devices can be configured to appear as a USB keyboard.  Usually, this configuration step entails scanning a manufacturer-provided sheet of "special" barcodes.

If you need more information (i.e. keycodes, etc.), the wikipedia [Human interface device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) points to the HID 1.12 specification.

Comment: I have written an embedded USB Host Driver. HID Devices (Keyboard, mouse etc.) working fine. But USB Barcode scanner doesnt work. When I insert a USB barcode reader, my driver sense it as a keyboard and initialize. After I want to read a barcode, but barcode reader is frozen. Application doesnt frozen.

Comment: If you have a keyboard driver working, it sounds like you have the problem covered from the HID device side.  I would then suspect a misconfiguration in the scanner.